Naming conventions for database tables
My WP will query some additional, non-core MySQL tables in the same database, populated by third-party app.
Are there any considerations, potential issues or bottlenecks about naming these tables as wp_ or like data_?

There's only one naming convention to remember, the WP table prefix. If you don't want to use it you can do whatever you want. WordPress only cares about its own tables, you can create any other tables you want.
Keep in mind though that the WordPress table prefix isn't always wp_, and it changes for each site in a multisite e.g. wp_2_, so don't hardcode the prefix when creating your SQL queries.

If I use wp_ to populate external data, what are issues on It?

It sounds like you're worried you'll mess up a system that does not exist, if you create new tables that have start with wp_ but do not have the same full name as an existing core table, then that is all you have done, WordPress does not care. The main issues are not technical but your own personal confidence. You could create millions of tables that start with wp_ as long as you don't mess with core tables. Is there a specific concern or hypothetical problem you're thinking of?
